# mod rewrite - redirect only to subfolders

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, directory, subdirectory

I currently have my main page at www and some files at www/files/*.
How could I block the access to /files itself, but allow users to access www/files/* without having to give each folder a separated .htaccess file and without changing my current htaccess file at www?